# Cypress - wait for xhr request which triggered by UI operation

Tags: cypress

I have an app with select element, when changing the select value, the page makes an XHR request to load some data and insert it to a table. I want cypress to wait till the request end, and after the data rendered on the table, then to check the number of table rows.

this is the code I currently have:

```
    cy.get('[name="pageselct"]').select('300'); // fire a request to load data

    // the below line get executed before the data actually loaded: 
    const totalTableRows = cy.get('#listingsData > tr').length;
```

how can I achieve it?

Comment: It should wait,  do you want to check the length of the table to be a certain length? Is the element with id listingsData in your dom already? Can you provide some more information? If you don't care about the XHR call, you could stub/mock it. The issue might be with your selector, the table #listingsData might already be there so it find it and does not wait. Are there table rows in that table before you make the XHR call? What length does it return? show us more of your HTML if you can.

Comment: Thanks, basically the table is already exists with 50 rows, this is the default view.
under the table, there is a select element with 3 options 50 / 100 / 300, when selecting 300, the app fire a http request to load more table rows, and when the data return from server, the app update the table rows based on the new data.

so i want to wait till the table gets the new data and append the new rows, and then check the length..

Comment: Ah ok, yes that make sense to why it is not waiting, because it find your element already and continues on, normally it will try to find the element and wait, but in your case it is already there.. I think the answer below will help you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Waiting for XHRs is easy in cypress.  See https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Alias for more info.

```
// Start the server that waits for routes
cy.server();

// Set the XHR up as a route, do not mock the return (unless you want to)
cy.route("GET", "/xhr/to/wait/for").as("getData");

// Fire a request to load data
cy.get('[name="pageselct"]').select('300');

// Wait for the route to complete
cy.wait("@getData");

// The below line will not get executed before the data actually loaded
const totalTableRows = cy.get('#listingsData > tr').length;
```

Comment: I think as of right now this is worth a try, I did not not know and I am better for it.